# Native Client Chrome Games

Tags: 11.10, google-chrome, intel, lenovo

So I've been trying to run some chrome applications that make use of Google's new technology of native client on my new desktop computer. They all give me errors when attempting to start the game. One of them does sometimes work but when it does, refreshing or closing the tab then opening the game again will result with it not working again. I have no graphics card only the on-board graphics built in the i5 CPU. My computer is a lenovo H330 and I'm running Ubuntu 11.10.

Here's a montage of the chrome applications and their corresponding errors. 
[image link](http://www.fayp.com/vi-zCBtW8.png)

note that the 'Bastion' game has seemingly every day given me a different error. There has been a total of four different errors it has given me. One that I didn't get was the first. Then the second different error is the one in the picture. The third is the error below and finally today it has given me a fourth error which is located below where the third error is. The bastion game seems to give more informative errors then the others.

```
Oh No! Bastion Has Stopped Working

This game requires a WebGL-compatible graphics card and that WebGL is enabled.

Please check to make sure you have a compatible card
with the latest drivers from your card manufacturer.
For a list of Chrome WebGL compatible cards, check out Chrome support.

Some versions of Chrome can disable WebGL,
please check chrome://flags to ensure it is enabled.


Oh No! Bastion Has Stopped Working

The game encountered an error and was forced to quit.
We're sorry for the inconvenience.
Your graphics card does not meet the minimum requirement to run the game.
Bastion requires a graphics card with at least 512MB of VRAM.
```

Why can't I run these NaCl compiled games? Here's the content of the /var/log/Xorg.0.log http://pastebin.com/9QWNpcX7 all the games work fine on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is WebGL rather than Native Client. The error tells you everything you need to know: Your current setup doesn't support WebGL, most likely because you didn't install the proper graphics driver.

> Your graphics card does not meet the minimum requirement to run the game.
>   Bastion requires a graphics card with at least 512MB of VRAM.

Find out more about WebGL and how to get it (possibly) running your computer here: http://get.webgl.org/

Comment: You say 'most likely because you didn't install the proper graphics driver.' but how do I get the proper driver for the built in graphics on the i5 CPU? Don't forget I mentioned before that I have no graphics PCI or PCIE video card present in the computer. Intels whole idea of having built in graphics on these i3, i5 and i7 CPU's seems to be more trouble then it's worth?

Comment: http://get.webgl.org/ should tell you everything you want to know. If I'm not mistaken, WebGL isn't supported on Intel graphics cards in Linux...

Answer (score 1):

I found a tutorial on playing Native client games on Linux [here](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2011/12/how-to-play-popular-action-rpg-bastion.html).

First you need to check native client is enabled in chrome://flags or not.

Secondly you need to enable WebGL by running the command:

```
google-chrome --enable-webgl --ignore-gpu-blacklist
```

You can also do the same thing by going to chrome://flags and enabling 'Override software rendering list'

Lastly native client currently only works with chrome. It seems that some chromium builds are blacklisted temporarily because of a bug. You may also need to install proprietary drivers to stop getting 'graphic card not compatible' errors.